# i got message WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

os : windows 10, google chrome version 80.0.3987.106, selenium version 3.141.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idokl.png)

I have searched for this problem and i figure out that gecko deals with firefox browser but im using chrome browser but why i got stuck with this.

here's my code.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${HOMEPAGE}    http://www.google.com
${BROWSER}    chrome

*** Test Cases ***
Go To homepage
    Open Browser    ${HOMEPAGE} ${BROWSER}
```

Please help, thanks u all.

Comment: Did you install chromedriver?

Comment: Please don't post images where you can copy/paste text and use Stackoverflows formatting.